# Send Linux command from C program

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm writing a C program to run in Linux shell.
Now I got a problem with such command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
char* command="history>>history";
system(command);
}
```

I want it to write the result of command "history" into a document, but it failed with a blank one.

If I change it to "date>>history", current system time will be written into the document.

Is there any problem with "history>>history"?
What should I do if I want to get that work?
Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want it to do here?

Comment: run `which history` and observe that it is... probably a shell builtin

Comment: if date writes to history, then maybe history doesn't write anything to stdout so you can redirect it with >> to a file,

Comment: Sorry, I want it to save the result of "history" to a document names "history".

Comment: is there a reason why you're using C for this, rather than a bash function?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `history` is not a real command but a shell builtin. Thus you can't call it from a C program[1].

Depending on the shell the user is using, you can instead get the history from `~/.bash_history`, `~/.zsh_history` and so on. Note however that zsh only write to this file at the end of a session.

[1] Well, you could theorically try `system("bash -c history")`, but you won't get the actual history because the builtin isn't run in the context of the current session.

Comment: Thank you for figuring out!